# Components not showing up in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing

I'm new to Java and Java GUI and I'm having trouble with Java Swing. Currently I have the following code:

```
public class Dashboard  {

Dashboard() {
    JFrame screen = new JFrame();
    JPanel window = new JPanel();
    JLabel title = new JLabel();

    title.setText("dashboard");
    title.setBounds(400,200,100,100);
    title.setVisible(true);
    window.add(title);
    GraphicsEnvironment ge = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
    File xkcd = new File("./bin/gui/xkcd-script.ttf");
    Font xkcdscript;
    try {
        xkcdscript = Font.createFont(0, xkcd);
        ge.registerFont(xkcdscript);
        title.setFont(xkcdscript);
    } catch (FontFormatException | IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    JMenuBar sidebar = new JMenuBar();


    window.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    window.add(sidebar);
    window.add(title);

    screen.add(window);
    screen.setExtendedState(java.awt.Frame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
    screen.setVisible(true);
}
```

Before I added the JPanel I had the sidebar showing up, but after adding it all of my elements disappeared. So far nothing I've tried has helped. 
I'm using Eclipse and Java13.

What should I change?

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). Take out the custom font, take out the menu bar. Cut the cruft unrelated to the problem, then add import statements and a main method.

Comment: BTW - don't add a `JMenuBar` to another component. Call `screen.setJMenuBar(..)` (<- look up the details - BNI).

Answer (score -1):

Welcome James. As a new contributor, please make sure to accept this answer if it helps.

The way you are building your code is going to cause you a massive headache. First, you should extend JFrame from your Dashboard class, then have a main method to instantiate your frame, and then have the constructor public Dashboard() where you can add all your components.

Something like this:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;

public class Dashboard extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                Dashboard frame = new Dashboard();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Dashboard() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
}

}
```

Hope this helps and good luck.

Comment: How does having Dashboard extend JFrame improve the code? I'm a little confused.

Comment: *"How does having Dashboard extend JFrame improve the code?"* It doesn't. Extending windows & components is rarely necessary, and this is a classic example of when it's **not necessary**. *"I'm a little confused."* Seemingly less so than the person supplying the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, but how come creating a JFrame with an IDE automatically creates it this way?

Comment: Oh and it makes no sense downvoting a working answer, a code automatically generated by a standard IDE that answers the questioned asked by the OP.